# Why Knockout ignore HTML Code Binding?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, winjs

I`m using KnockoutJS to bind to a table in WINJS App , when I run My App at the first time , it runs well with correct binding . 
this is the Row.innetHTML =

```
 <tbody id="repeater" data-bind="foreach: labsTableArrayKo"     
  <tr class="tr">
        <td><span data-bind="text: VlabName"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: VMType"></span></td>
        <td>
           <div data-bind="if: VMType == 'Virtual Machine'">
             <span  data-bind="text: vmStatus"></span>
           </div>
           <div data-bind="if: VMType == 'RemoteApp'">
             <span  data-bind="text: 'Ready'"></span>
           </div>
        </td>
  </tr>
```

but when I change Array which use in binding , Some of HTML Code is Deleted ( I dont know How ?! ) . 
the Row.InnetHTML is =

```
                 <tr class="tr">
                     <td><span data-bind="text:VlabName"></span></td>
                     <td><span data-bind="text: VMType"></span></td>
                     <td>
                      <div data-bind="if: VMType == 'Virtual Machine'"></div>
                      <div data-bind="if: VMType == 'RemoteApp'"></div>
                    </td>

                </tr>
```

here is how I bind To HTML Code by Javascript :

```
 var viewModel = {labsTableArrayKo: labs_Table_Array};
 ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("repeater"));
 var q = document.getElementById("repeater").innerHTML;
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("repeater"));
```

So what is the problem ??

Comment: What is the value of `VMType`? The `if` binding does not render the HTML of its contents if its condition isn't true.

Comment: How are you constructing items in labsTableArrayKo? Are object in that array POCO's or are they constructed using knockout observables? If members like VlabName and VMType are observables then you should check expressions in the 'if' bindings. It could be that expression VMType == 'Virtual Machine' evaluates to false because VMType is a function (an observable) - in that case you should write that expression like: VMType() == 'Virtual Machine'. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Roy J , I didn`t know that before .. thanks for that .

Answer (score 0):

actually I replaced (If) with (visible) and it works with me , I don't know exactly why but it works .